# retrieve the object which have empty array from a particular document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I have some documents of nested object. And I want to retrieve those object group them with the nested object which have empty array using agregation.

let me explain more accurately-
suppose my collection consist of documents given bellow---

document 1

```
{
    "_id": "17202155",
    "completed": [
      "cse331",
      "cse312"
    ],
    "incompleted": [
      {
        "name": "math",
        "preReq": []
      },
      {
        "name": "science",
        "preReq": [
          "bang",
          "eng",
          "math"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "astronomy",
        "preReq": [
          "bang",
          "eng",
          "science"
        ]
      }
    ]   },
```

document 2

```
{
    "_id": "17202157",
    "completed": [
      "cse331",
      "cse312"
    ],
    "incompleted": [
      {
        "name": "math",
        "preReq": []
      },
      {
        "name": "science",
        "preReq": []
      },
      {
        "name": "astronomy",
        "preReq": [
          "bang",
          "eng",
          "science"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

i want to retrieve the documents group by the id with the object consist of empty array. That means the result will be --

```
{
    "_id": "17202155",
    "incompleted": [
      {
        "name": "math",
        "preReq": []
      },
      
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "17202157",
    "incompleted": [
      {
        "name": "math",
        "preReq": []
      },
      {
        "name": "science",
        "preReq": []
      },
    ]
  }
```

i have use this code but it doesnot works. Though i am new to mongodb. please help me--

> #my code-

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$unwind": "$_id"
},
{
  "$group":{"_id": "$incompleted",}
},
{
  "$match": {
    "_id.preReq": {
      $size: 0
    }
  }
},
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$incompleted"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "incompleted.preReq": []
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      incompleted: {
        $push: "$incompleted"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JTZ_RkSaqSi)